# Extracting capture groups in shifting order

Tags: unix, sed, terminal

I'm having some trouble figuring out how to capture two patterns that come in shifting order from a text file and printing them in the same order. For example, we have this textfile:

```
13234::ABC
ABDE:1234
123::DUF
```

What if I wanted to output it like this:

```
13234 ABC
1234 ABDE
123 DUF
```

Meaning, I want to first find all the digits and then all the characters no matter what order they come in in the textfile, and then output digits followed by characters.

How would I go about doing this? I can only figure out how to do it if they always come in the same order in the text file.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack Overflow is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Answer (score 3):

**`sed`** solution (considering that there could be only one number sequence):

```
sed -r 's/([0-9]*):*([a-zA-Z]+):*([0-9]*)/\1\3 \2/' inputfile
```

The output:

```
13234 ABC
1234 ABDE
123 DUF
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering that your Input_file will be same as shown samples. In case you are ok with `awk` then try following.

```
awk '
match($0,/[0-9]+/){
  dig=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
}
match($0,/[a-zA-Z]+/){
  print dig, substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  dig=""
}
'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
13234 ABC
1234 ABDE
123 DUF
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in an awk solution

```
awk -F ":+" '($1+0==$1){print $1,$2; next}{print $2,$1}'
```

The idea is to check if the first column is a number, if it is print the original order, otherwise reverse it.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'h;s/[^[:alpha:]]//g;x;s/[^[:digit:]]//g;G;s/\n/ /' file
```

Split the problem into two: make a copy of the current line, remove everything but the alphabetic characters from the first, remove everything but the digits from the second, append the first to the second and replace the newline by a space.

Answer (score -1):

Using Perl

```
$ cat lunark.txt
13234::ABC
ABDE:1234
123::DUF
$ perl -F"/:+/" -alne ' print $F[0]=~/\d+/ ? "$F[0] $F[1]" : "$F[1] $F[0]" ' lunark.txt
13234 ABC
1234 ABDE
123 DUF
$
```